# sorting mutable array in alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am having a nsmutable array and in that nearly 50 -60 object having different names ,and can i sort this array in alphabetical order (Is it possible, How?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a simple sort like this, I like to use sort descriptors.

Suppose you have an mutable array of objects whose class has a `name` NSString property:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: This will start with "W" and not with "A". How to start with "A"?

Comment: I got ascending order first CAPS and small letters. Like "A to Z" and then "a to z". What I need to do.

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely, you can use [`sortUsingSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

If your array has custom objects, then you will need to implement a sorting method on those objects:

```
@implementation myCustomObject
  ...

  -(NSComparisonResult) compare:(myCustomObject*) other {
      return [self.name compare:other.name];
  }

@end
```

Comment: nice one line answer (for simple arrays).

Answer (score 2):

TechZen's approach works well, but it would work better if you used NSSortDescriptor's +sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:, passing "localizedCompare:" as the selector. This way, the sorting is localized to the user's language, which can make a big difference in string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray=[myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Simply Worked for me!

Comment: hmm .. what's the difference to earlier answers?